# Scala: add items to a sequence or merge sequences conditionally

Tags: scala, scala-collections, seq

I need to add an item to a `Seq` depending on a condition.

The only thing I have been able to do is:

```
if(condition){
    part1 ++ part2 ++ Seq(newItem)
}
else {
  part1 ++ part2
}
```

`part1` and `part2` are `Seq[String]`.
It works but there is a lot of repeated code. Any way to do this better?
Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your case third part can be `Option`al:

```
val part3 = if (condition) Some(newItem) else None
part1 ++ part2 ++ part3
```

Example:

```
scala> Seq(1,2,3) ++ Seq(4,5) ++ Option(6)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

Here implicit conversion [Option.option2Iterable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option$.html#option2Iterable[A](xo:Option[A]):Iterable[A]) is doing the trick.

Answer (score 2):

`part1 ++ part2 ++ Some(newItem).filter(_ => condition)`

Answer (score 2):

Consider also `Seq.empty` on an if-else expression, as follows,

```
part1 ++ part2 ++ (if (condition) Seq(newItem) else Seq.empty)
```

For instance

```
Seq("a") ++ Seq("b") ++ (if (true) Seq("c") else Seq.empty)
List(a, b, c)

Seq("a") ++ Seq("b") ++ (if (false) Seq("c") else Seq.empty)
List(a, b)
```